# PyCharm how to turn off inline variable explorer

Tags: pycharm

Sorry for dumb question but this has been driving me crazy, and I couldn't find anything online that mentioned it, probably because I don't know what it's called. I probably turned it on with some shortcut by mistake, and now I can't turn it off.

[image]

How can I get rid of this variable viewer?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are under the debugger - disable **Show Values Inline**:

[image]

Comment: That would help, but I am not in the debugger.

Comment: Is it a Jupyter notebook? **Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Jupyter | Show Inline Values in the Editor** should help.

Answer (score 0):

In Mac version 2022.2 of PyCharm, the toggle for showing or not showing inline values in Jupyter notebooks is in:

Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | Jupyter | Show inline values in editor